# Python can not open UTF-8 encoded text file

Tags: python, powershell, utf-8

I have .py script which contains following code to open specific text file (which was generated by Exchange Powershell):

```
with codecs.open("C:\\Temp\\myfile.txt",encoding="utf_8",mode="r",errors="replace") as myfile:
    content = myfile.readlines() #here we convert lines to list
    print(content)
```

however, i tried also utf-16-be and utf-16-le (and standard ASCII obviously), but the file output is still looking like this (this is just part of it):

```
['��\r', '\x00\n', '\x00D\x00o\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00n\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00\r', '\x00\n', '\x00-\x00-\x00-\x00-\x00-\x00-\x00
```

the file which i am trying to open is [located here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmOO00U_9_nugd5qpZvBjCh_juXOjA)

does anybody please know what am i doing wrong? Is this some different kind of encoding?

Comment: This is not a UTF-8 encoded text file, so your problem is wrong from the start. From those first two bytes showing up as "missing character" glyphs, I'd guess this is BOM-encoded UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this text is definitely not UTF-8, so that's why Python can't open it as a UTF-8-encoded text file.

Second, you claim you "tried also utf-16-be and utf-16-le", but didn't show how you did that, and I suspect you did it wrong.

From the output, this is very likely BOM-encoded UTF-16-LE.

The first two bytes—because of the way you've printed them, we can't tell which bytes they are, but this is what it looks like when you print out `\xFF` and `\xFE` bytes. And the rest of the strings are a bunch of NUL even bytes alternating with reasonable-looking bytes, which almost always means UTF-16-LE. Plus, most common two-byte with a BOM in the wild is UTF-16-LE, and the fact that you're using all Microsoft tools makes that even more likely.

So, if you'd really tried `utf-16-le`, you would almost certainly have gotten the right string, but with an extra `\ufeff` at the start.

But of course the right answer is to just decode it as 'utf-16', which will consume and use the BOM properly.

Comment: Well if i use utf-16-le (just in code instead of utf_8) it "works", but now i see it like "stairs" (+1 tab on each line)... i know it is usable for me, but why there are these tabs? is it possible to remove them somehow? Thanks

Comment: @JanMusil I don't know why you're seeing "stairs". Post a complete example of code and data that I can run that shows that, and maybe I can help you. Or, better, post it as a new question, and the whole SO community can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to open a file encoded in 'UTF-16' in UTF-8.

UTF-16 allows a Byte Order Mark (BOM), a code point with the value U+FEFF, to precede the first actual coded value.
The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text stream can signal several things to a program consuming the text:

- What byte order, or endianness, the text stream is stored in; The
  fact that the text stream is Unicode, to a high level of confidence;
- Which of several Unicode encodings that text stream is encoded as.
- BOM use is optional, and, if used, should appear at the start of the 
  text stream.

If you open the file as "rb" i.e with the intention to read it as a byte stream this should be the first line of the output:-

```
b'\xff\xfe\r\x00\n'
```

This is the BOM I was talking about.

If you run the following code:-

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-16") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line)
```

your output will have no errors.

If you need to use UTF-8 for a some specific reason try to update the input file in byte format and removing the first line i.e.  `b'\xff\xfe\r\x00\n'`
Though I am not sure about the specifics.

For more refer:-]

[BOM](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

[UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes)

Comment: Manually removing the BOM will certainly not make the file interpretable as UTF-8!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"utf-16"` instead of `"utf_8"`.